# OOP : When should I subclass and when should I <include>

Tags: objective-c, oop

I am wondering when I should subclass and I should include, let me explain you why :

- I saw that whenever you include a class, you can access to it's methods, for example, if I create a new class that is a subclass of NSObject, I can still access to NSString and its methods just by including NSString.h
- I also read that when you create a class that is a subclass of another class, you also access to it's methods.

So as a beginner to Objective-C, I just don't when should I use the first one and when should I use the second one ?

Comment: This really isn't an Objective-C question, it's really a basic Object Orientated Programming (OOP) question.

Comment: @rmaddy Edited the title and tags in consequence.

Comment: The answer is slightly different in Objective-C than in C++, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing is an object-oriented programming technique for creating a subtype of an existing type that inherits the supertype's behavior. `#include` is a compiler directive that substitutes the contents of the named file in its place. The two have very little to do with each other except that you have to include the file that declares a class in order to subclass it.

This question is kind of like "When should I build a doghouse and when should I use a hammer?"

Comment: Ok, thank you, there is something that I don't understand at all : if I need to #include to create a subclass, what is exactly the point to create a subclass since I don't even need to that to access to the other class because I already included it ?

Comment: How did you get "if I need to #include to create a subclass" from what he said? lol. They really don't have anything to do with each other, and that's what he said.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: You don't create a subclass to access another class. You create a subclass to add more specialized behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a class that does what you want it to do, you can just use it. That's what you would do with NSString, for example.

When you need a new class that has nothing to do with any existing class, you subclass NSObject. Since NSObject is the subclass of everything in Objective-C, many people won't count that actually as "subclassing" but just as creating a new class.

When you need a class that is a modified version of an existing class, you subclass that class. However, Objective-C gives you some tools to avoid subclassing, and you shouldn't create a subclass unless you really have to. For example, you can add methods and even instance variables to existing classes without creating a subclass, and many classes are configurable through the use of delegate objects.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, so... to summarize what you said : I should simply import and avoid as much as possible to subclass ? If for example I create a class that does mathematics, and an other class that does geometry, since I need some math functions in geometry, should I create my geometry class as a sub lass of my math class or should I simply include my math class in my geometry class ?

Comment: You said *"NSObject is the subclass of everything in Objective-C"*. This isn't true. `NSObject` is the root class of (almost) everything in Objective-C.

Comment: It may help you to read: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html  which explains in part classes and have a look at the Foundation Framework Reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/objc_classic/_index.html. Which when added to your project gives you access to many of the classes you will need to use in your code and your own classes. Which means you will have for example access to the NSString class without including it your self directly.